# Xampp sql data data base error 1049. Where do i save the sql file in xampp?

Tags: php, sql, database, xampp

im really new to this, just a hobby, but my hobby is killing me now. I have my config.php,

```
define('DB_SERVER' , 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME' , 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD' , '');
define('DB_NAME' , 'stock.sql');
```

and my file is currently saved in /localhost/php/mySite.com/
so when I run my code thru xampp I get this error:

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'stock.sql' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\mySite.com\config.php on line 13
ERROR: Could not connect. Unknown database 'stock.sql'

Any ideas?

I did try moving the file out to htdocs, and also

```
define ['DB_NAME' , '/localhost/php/mySite/stock.sql
```

my first time doing a data base so don't really know how to connect the database.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: The `sql` is probably a dump file, not the actual database. You'll need to load that file into mysql.

Comment: I do have my sql file, my php config file, and my php index file, what I don't understand is where do I save the sql filein xampp? does it go in the same file as the index file or is there another file for it cause xampp says it cant connect to the database when I execute my index file

Comment: It needs to be loaded into the MySQL program. You can use the command line or use something like MySQL workbench